# How can I remove this child from my pane?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have created a method similar to this for spawning graphics randomly to the stage. I want to attach an event listener to them so when clicked they are removed:

```
    public static void createcircle(){
                Circle mycircle = new Circle();
                mycircle.setRadius(10.0);
                window.layout.getChildren().addAll(mycircle);
                mycircle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->window.layout.getChildren().remove(mycircle));
            }
```

As "Lambda expression's parameter e cannot re-declare another local variable defined in an enclosing" what other methods can be used for declaring an event for destruction.

Comment: what's the problem with your snippet?

Comment: Can you describe what is **window** here?

Comment: `e` seems to be declared somewhere in a surrounding scope. If the code snippet is close enough to your real code, it must be a field, but my guess in general would be that you nested event handlers used the same identifier (`e`)  as name for both parameters...

Comment: @MayurPatel 'window' is a class for the JavaFX application and the shape is being created on a 'static Pane' called 'layout.'

Comment: @fabian yes, it was a naming conflict, rewritten with no returned error.